# Concepts like a pushout or pullback but slightly different

Tags: category-theory

I'm currently reading [these](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~eriehl/266x/basic.pdf) short lecture notes and had a question regarding example 2.6(d) (also I think there is a typo in there, but I'm not sure. Anyway...)

In the given category $J$, consisting of three objects $A, B, C$ with morphisms $f, g$ from $C$ to $A, B$, respectively, the notes state that...

- A pullback is the limit of a $J$-shaped diagram
- A pushout is the colimit of a $J^{op}$-shaped diagram

But what about the limit of a $J^{op}$-shaped diagram? Or the colimit of a $J$-shaped diagram? Do these limits and colimits have a name? Are there any elementary examples in which these arise? I haven't seen them before! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are "uninteresting" in the following sense. The pullback of a pushout diagram $A \leftarrow B \rightarrow C$ is the identity arrow $B \to B$ (exercise). The dual statement for pullback diagrams is true by duality. The point is that these diagrams, in these directions, aren't imposing an interesting universal property.

Comment: To add on this, if $J$ has an initial object $j_0$, then $\lim_J F \cong F(j_0)$ (and the same is true for colimits and terminal objects).

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're saying. I think I was able to solve that little exercise! And thanks, Najib, that helps, and should help whenever I look at another diagram and have the same kind of question again.